# if_else double criteria condition in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

```
PID D1  D2  D3
123 0   0   0
234 0   0   1
456 0   1   0
666 0   1   1
555 1   0   0
777 1   1   1
```

I need to identify the single marked Drug(D) columns like below

Expected output

```
PID D1  D2  D3  Flag
123 0   0   0   NA
234 0   0   1   3
456 0   1   0   2
666 0   1   1   NA
555 1   0   0   1
777 1   1   1   NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rowSums` to count number of `NA` in each row and `max.col` to get the corresponding index if you have only one 1 in the row.

```
ifelse(rowSums(df[-1] == 1) == 1, max.col(df[-1]), NA)
#[1] NA  3  2 NA  1 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this without `ifelse`

```
 max.col(df1[-1], 'first') * NA^(rowSums(df1[-1])!= 1)
 #[1] NA  3  2 NA  1 NA
```